# How do you do a for-loop in pact?

Tags: pact-lang

I'd like to loop over an array of values. Something like

```
for each foo in bar[] do
{
foo.doSomething
}
```

How do I do this in pact?

I see in your todomvc example that you get a value back from the blockchain and use map within the react framework to effectively iteratate through this

https://github.com/kadena-io/pact-todomvc/blob/master/src/components/todo-app.jsx#L94

But can you do this within the pact language itself? Something akin to a cursor function in Oracle PL/SQL

Answer (score 3):

Pact has a built-in function `map` that lets you iterate through a list.

See here for the detailed description: https://pact-language.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pact-functions.html#map

```
(map (do-something) bar)
```

would do what you described.

Comment: Thanks! Super helpful

Answer (score 1):

So here's an example of this now in use. In this case, add one to each number in the list

```
pact> (map (+ 1) [1 2 3])
[2 3 4]
```